# How to apply .patch file to project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, svn, patch, ankhsvn

I created a .patch file from my changes on my laptop with Ankhsvn for a MVC4-project. Now I am on another computer where I loaded the MVC-project from SVN and I want to apply this patch. I have no idea how to do this, and cannot find it in the manual.

What I do know is that I cannot apply a patch:

[image: No option to apply a patch]

Furthermore, I don't know how this .patch file is supposed to work since it also needs to add images and new files.

Can someone explain to me how I can use the .patch file?

Comment: [Can't](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=263756&dsForumId=582). You need to use some other tool, such as TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @crashmstr Okay, is that enough to apply the patch?

Comment: If you have TortoiseSVN, you can apply patches, yes. [Creating and Applying Patches](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnkhSVN requires you to use an external patch tool. Otherwise the 'Apply patch' option is greyed out. You can install TortoiseSVN and configure AnkhSVN to use it's merging tool for apply patches.